# Why does the closure compiler create void 0 instead of shorter alternatives?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Comparing these strings:

```
{}[0]
[][0]
void 0
```

Why does [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) generate

```
void 0
```

when it could generate

```
[][0]
```

or

```
{}[0]
```

or even

```
[].a
```

as torazaburo mentioned
which are 1 character shorter?

Comment: What is the "closure compiler"?

Comment: https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/

Comment: Isn't `[].a` even shorter?

Comment: @torazaburo, that's a good idea.

Comment: `Array.prototype.a = 'hi';` would break `[].a`. But in addition to guaranteed correctness, the other reason to use `void 0` is performance.

Comment: If you use undefined a lot, you can reduce it to 1 or 2 character(s) long by doing `var u;`, then `console.log(u)` will log undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimum code size isn't the only goal of the Closure compiler. Another goal (I assume) is to generate code that is as fast as the original.

`void 0` is likely to be faster across various JavaScript runtimes. It doesn't have to construct an object or array and dereference a nonexistent property.

A JavaScript runtime engine could possibly optimize away the `{}[0]` or `[][0]`, but why would the Closure compiler want to depend on that? If those don't get optimized away, they would be significantly slower than `void 0`.

Keep in mind that JavaScript code is usually downloaded in compressed form, and if `void 0` appears in multiple places they are likely to get compressed out.

Also see Blaise's answer for another good reason not to use `{}[0]` or `[][0]`.

Answer (score 4):

`{}[0]` doesn't (always? see comments) return undefined, and `[][0]` could in theory return something other than undefined since you can override Array constructors/getters.

Comment: `{}[0]` does evaluate to undefined, but the same reasoning holds.

Comment: @JJJ That's odd, in Firefox 53 it returns `Array[0]`. `{}[0] === void 0 // false` and `[][0] === void 0 // true`

Comment: That's because of the console – I believe it interprets it as an empty block followed by an array declaration. `({}[0])` should print undefined.

Comment: Please give an example of an Array constructor/getter override that could change the value of `[][0]`.

Comment: @torazaburo: `Object.defineProperties( Array.prototype, { '0': { get: function() { return 'hi'; } } } );`

Comment: Wouldn't this break almost all javascript?

Comment: Or more simply, `Array.prototype[0] = 'hi';`. But yes, you're right, this would break a lot of JavaScript code. For a more subtle case, consider the suggestion to use `[].a`. Then `Array.prototype.a = 'hi';` would break it while being much less likely to break other code.